# Creating a Vault

Tags: modeling

In Blender is it possible and how  to subtract/remove the parts of the two tubes that are under the roof of the structure? I tried boolean subtract but it's not doing it for me or maybe i am using it the wrong way.

[image: In blender]

Comment: You might find this helpful if you are considering using *Geometry Nodes*: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261838/

Answer (score 3):

You could use the *Mirror* modifier: Create your tunnel (here it is aligned on Z), create 2 empties that you put at the same location:

[image]

Give your object a *Mirror* modifier with one of your empties as *Mirror Object*, enable the *Axis* and *Bisect* options (here on X), rotate the empty -45° on Z:

[image]

Give it a second *Mirror* modifier with the other empty as *Mirror Object*, enable the *Axis* and *Bisect* options (here on X again), rotate the empty -135° on Z:

[image]

Comment: Would it be fair to call this Q and your A a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/193965/35559 ?

Comment: Sure, except my answer here is better

Comment: It's snappier, for sure. Let's leave it be, unless others start voting it out.

Comment: Thanks' I'll try it!